# How to convert GA API JSON to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, sql-server, pandas, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a connector Google Analytics to MS SQL Server and in order to load the GA info to a DB Table the API response should be normalized. I thought pd.Dataframe is not a bad idea.

API Responce v3

```
{'columnHeaders': [{'columnType': 'DIMENSION',
                    'dataType': 'STRING',
                    'name': 'ga:yearMonth'},
                   {'columnType': 'DIMENSION',
                    'dataType': 'STRING',
                    'name': 'ga:year'},
                   {'columnType': 'METRIC',
                    'dataType': 'INTEGER',
                    'name': 'ga:users'},
                   {'columnType': 'METRIC',
                    'dataType': 'INTEGER',
                    'name': 'ga:sessions'}],
 'containsSampledData': False,
 'id': 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:*****&dimensions=ga:yearMonth,ga:year&metrics=ga:users,ga:sessions&start-date=2019-01-01&end-date=2019-01-31&start-index=1',
 'itemsPerPage': 1000,
 'kind': 'analytics#gaData',
 'profileInfo': {'accountId': '****',
                 'internalWebPropertyId': '***',
                 'profileId': '***',
                 'profileName': 'All Web Site Data',
                 'tableId': 'ga:178030957',
                 'webPropertyId': 'UA-****-1'},
 'query': {'dimensions': 'ga:yearMonth,ga:year',
           'end-date': '2019-01-31',
           'ids': 'ga:****',
           'max-results': 1000,
           'metrics': ['ga:users', 'ga:sessions'],
           'start-date': '2019-01-01',
           'start-index': 1},
 'rows': [['201901', '2019', '3677', '4501']],
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:****&dimensions=ga:yearMonth,ga:year&metrics=ga:users,ga:sessions&start-date=2019-01-01&end-date=2019-01-31&start-index=1',
 'totalResults': 1,
 'totalsForAllResults': {'ga:sessions': '4501', 'ga:users': '3677'}}
```

I want to include in df the following params: query info, profileInfo and rows.

So far I've tried accessing json through json_normalize function, but it doesn't convert the response properly :(

```py
 df_test=json_normalize(traffic_results)
```

It produces df with nested dicts

Then I've tried to pass record_path and meta info:

```py
df_example=json_normalize(traffic_results, record_path=['rows'], meta=[['query', 'dimensions'], ['query', 'metrics']])
```

Get rows and then dimensions and metrics, but it produces an error:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.

But when I pass these args:

```py
response_ga_report=json_normalize(traffic_results, record_path=['rows'], meta=[['query' , 'ids'], ['query' , 'dimensions']])
```

It works ok:

```py
     0       1       2       3       query.ids      query.dimensions
0   201901  2019    3677    4501    ga:178030957    ga:yearMonth,ga:year
```

I'm deeply stuck, have no idea how it can be converted. It's not mandatory to convert the response in DF.